# Is my Internet connection worsened by having multiple separate powerline adapters?

Tags: ethernet, powerline-networking

I have 2 separate  powerline adapters. The Internet connection appears to have deteriorated once I set up the second adapter. Does having a number of adapters have an impact on the connection?

Comment: Do you mean two separate adapter *pairs* or just two adapters in total? It doesn't sound very useful to have only one adapter in the network...

Comment: @user1686 He may have a router with build-in PowerLine and 2 separate PowerLine adapters. In that is the case the 2nd adapter will degrade performance no matter what. I will add that case to my answer. (I forgot about that possibility.)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely yes.
Powerline is very similar to Wifi (it essentially sends Wifi via the power-circuitry in stead of via a radio-link).
Like Wifi it uses channels. Each set of Powerline adapters selects a channel to work on.
And, same as with Wifi, if 2 sets select the same channel or (partially) overlapping channels you will get interference which degrades both throughput and latency.

In some PowerLine setups you can manually assign the channels via the web-interface of the adapters. If that is not possible best you can do is unplug one of the adapters and plug it back in, in the hope it will re-establish it connection to the other side on a different channel.

Another thing:
If both sets are from the same brand it is possible that all 4 adapters go onto the same channel in a 4-device setup. (The 2nd set extends the 1 set. It doesn't act as a separate set.)
In that case performance is also impacted as that means that all 4 devices share the same channel and have to wait until it is their turn to send. (There can only be 1 active sender at any time on each channel.)
You can easily verify if this is the case by unplugging 1 Powerline adapter and see if the other 3 keep working. If that is the case you have this 4-device setup.
If this happens to you the only way around it will be by re-configuring the adapters in their web-interfaces (if they have those).

Last but not least:
You may have a 3-device setup with a PowerLine end-point in your router and 2 separate adapters.
In that case the 2nd adapter will always have to be on the same channel so it will degrade performance for equipment connected to EACH PowerLine adapter.

To conclude:
PowerLine works best in pairs. Each additional adapter added to a pair will degrade performance to some extend.

Comment: Not all powerline adapters are WiFi and the data transmitted over the structure's wiring isn't WiFi. Powerline adapters transmit data over electrical wiring at [20Mhz - 20Ghz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication) ranges, so it would seem unlikely non-WiFi powerline adapters would be programmed to transmit data in the 2.4Ghz - 2.5Ghz and 5.1Ghz - 5.9Ghz ranges. Reference links would be helpful =]

Comment: @JW0914 I never said they used the same frequency range. But the way they work is very similar. Then even use the same encryption scheme (WEP in old PowerLine stuff and WPA2-PSK in newer) and a WPS like pairing mechanism.

Comment: Stating "_...it essentially sends Wifi via the power-circuitry instead of via a radio-link_" is factually inaccurate, as it does not send WiFi over the electrical lines, operating more akin to ethernet, but with a broader frequency range to limit AC noise. If they don't use the same frequency range, how is one supposed to interfere with the other, especially when it's transmitting over electrical lines, not WiFi? Outside of EMF induction, which wouldn't be strong enough with low voltage communications, there's no way for the data transmitted via electrical lines to interfere with WiFi

Comment: @JW0914 Who said anything about interference with WIFI? I didn't. They interfere with each other (if multiple PL devices get into the same frequency range, which is similar to multiple Wifi AP's getting in each other way). And your "operating more akin to ethernet" I find a weird statement. Both WIFI and PowerLine ARE ethernet over a non-UTP medium with very similar extensions to define frequency channels in their respective transmission medium and with identical solutions to segregate traffic (aka define broadcast domains) by means of encryption.